# Test domain shows blank page

Tags: server, apache2

I just created a test domain for my laravel application.

here is the steps I followed

I created a config file named `run.test.conf` under the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@run.test
     DocumentRoot /var/www/run/public
     ServerName run.test

     <Directory /var/www/run/public>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

then run followed commands

```
sudo a2ensite run.test
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

after that I opened the /etc/hosts file and put above line at bottom

```
127.0.0.1 run.test
```

when I finished, I restarted the apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

run.test domain is working, but its open blank page.

I checked laravel if there is something wrong. I opened application with `php artisan serve` command but there is no error, it's working well..

I don't why local domain doesn't work.. Did I something wrong ?

Comment: Create a simple `hello.html` page in /var/www/run/public` with just `Hello...`. Check if you can open `localhost/hello.html` or `run.test/hello.html`.

Comment: @estibordo yep, it's able to open html content, so.. is php causes that error ?

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: @pa4080 homepage ?

Comment: Homepage of what? Is there `index.php` or `index.html` in `/var/www/run/public`?

Comment: @pa4080 yes it is

Comment: You can tray to add the following directive: `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` (maybe something is wrong with the global definition of that directive). Also try to flush your browsers cache (Ctrl+F5, or Ctrl+Shift+R - depending on your browser). If the problem is the php module you should see the php code as raw text.

Comment: Next step is to create `phpinfo.php` under `/var/www/run/public` with just: `<?php phpinfo( ); ?>`. Then open `localhost/phpinfo.php`.

Comment: @estibordo it shows php version as well

Comment: @HasanTingir Not bad. You have Apache and PHP up and running. Let's see why your site is still blank. 1. Check on the client side. Open Developer tools on the browser. Open the site and check the console looking for errors and the network to know which files you have received (if any). 2. Check on the server side. Look at the folder `/var/log/apache2` the `error.log` file. Check if you there any errors there.

Comment: @estibordo I solved brother, thanks for your help :) it was about permissions